# Executar JNLP Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Minha versão atual do java é a seguinte:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Porém não consigo executar um arquivo `.jnlp`
Como faço para executar esse java ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Acredito que você precise do *javaws*

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-netx
```

Você também pode tentar seguir algum tutorial, como [esse](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/12/how-to-run-jnlp-files-under-ubuntulinux.html)